# Differentiability of Convex and Monotone Function and $F_{\sigma}$ sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis

Consider  $f: I \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. I know that if $f$ is convex then $f$ is differentiable except in a countable set. Alexandroff theorem states that $f$ is twice
differentiable except at a set of null measure. My first question is: Is the set that $f$ is twice differentiable $F_{\sigma}$?

Similarly, if $f$ is monotone then $f$ is differentiable except at a set of null measure. Is this set $F_{\sigma}$?

Comment: I'm not sure if the set where $f$ is twice differentiable is $F_\sigma$, but for sure it contains a conull $F_\sigma$ set

Comment: $f : I \subset \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$. "\to", not "\mapsto". Mapsto is used to indicate a particular function by showing how it transforms objects. For example $f : x \mapsto x^2$ is the same as saying "for all $x, f(x) = x^2$.

Comment: Just passing through and don't have time to really think about this now, but maybe something (including the references) in the following two sci.math posts could be of help: [Convex function -> continuous?](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/N_ieUBxZr-0/m/TbgF32bcHKsJ) (28 December 2002) and [ESSAY ON NON-DIFFERENTIABILITY POINTS OF MONOTONE FUNCTIONS](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/8vp1XK0-KNg/m/UOmRLJmd0xsJ) (4 November 2000).

Comment: In the second question, which set do you want to be an $F_\sigma$? The points of differentiability or the complement?

Answer (score 2):

Let $D=\{d_j\}_{j \ge 1}$ be a countable dense set in $I=(0,1)$.
Let $f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{-j} {\mathbf  1}_{[d_j,1)}(x)$ and
$g(x)=\int_0^1 f(t) dt$.
Then $g$ is monotone, and the set of points in $I$ where it is differentiable
is $I \setminus D$. This is not an $F_\sigma$ set, since if it was  a countable union of closed sets, then $I$ would be a countable union of nowhere dense closed sets, contradicting the Baire category theorem. Note that $D$ is also the set of points in $I$ where the convex function $h(x)=\int_0^1 g(t) dt$ is not twice differentiable.